How to properly free a Cuda context?
I am implementing Optix denoising inside my C++ path tracer. I then need to create a Cuda context before calling Optix kernels. That context should be created every time i spawn a rendering thread since each thread have its own Cuda context
According to the Optix sample, Cuda is initialized with that piece of code:
CudaFree(nullptr)

Then i need to free this before my thread exits. How to do so? Or there is nothing that needs to be done?

"According to the Optix sample, Cuda is initialized with that piece of code:" <- That's not a trustworthy way to initialize anything. If you want to initialize the CUDA driver (not the runtime; which I would generally avoid) - the call is cuInit().

cudaFree(nullptr) frees a non-existing pointer. Per the CUDA runtime documentation, no action is taken when a null pointer is freed:

If devPtr is 0, no operation is performed.

Therefore, no action is required on your end. Thanks!
